# sound problem on high level of memory usage

Tags: 11.04, sound, memory-usage

I'm under Ubuntu 11.04 and I have 3GB memory

Everthing's working good, but when the usage of memory is overcoming more then ~80% then the sound is crached. It sounds like a speaker is broken, you can hear only squeaky sound.

To fix this problem I have to reboot the system.

Is there the posibility to resolve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution does not fully solve the problem but makes it a little easier to fix.

```
pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start
```